# algorithm: get the last and next events by current date from array (javascript / angular)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, algorithm, object

Can somebody help me with an algorithm ?

I have a list of events and I want to get the next event and the previous events by current date.

**Example**

I get all events from sql database like this:

```
events = [
    {eventId:1, eventDate: "Wen Apr 01 2015 18:41:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace":'Dortmund, DE'},
    {eventId:2, eventDate: "Sun Apr 05 2015 23:41:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace":'Budapest, HU'},
    {eventId:3, eventDate: "Fri Apr 03 2015 13:41:00 GMT+0300" eventPlace":'Madrid, ES'},
    {eventId:4, eventDate: "Mon Jun 01 2015 22:00:00 GMT+0300" eventPlace":'London, EN'},
    .......
    {eventId:100, eventDate: "Mon Aug 31 2015 22:00:00 GMT+0300"}
    ]
```

If current date is Sun Apr 05 2015 15:00:00 I want to get

```
    resultNextEv= {eventId:2, eventDate: "Sun Apr 05 2015 23:41:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace":'Budapest, HU'}
    resultLastEv= {eventId:3, eventDate: "Fri Apr 03 2015 13:41:00 GMT+0300" eventPlace":'Madrid, ES'}
```

How is the best way to get this result. (I'm using javascript / angular )
Any ideea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, sort the events by date:

```
var sorted= events.sort(function(a,b) {
  return new Date(a.eventDate) - new Date(b.eventDate);
});
```

Then, iterate through the sorted events.  If a date is less than the target date, set that as the previous event.  If it's greater than the target date, set that as the next event, and stop iterating:

```
function getDates() {
  var sorted= events.sort(function(a,b) {
    return new Date(a.eventDate) - new Date(b.eventDate);
  });
  var date= new Date(document.getElementById('date').value),
      i,sdate;

  for(i = 0 ; i < sorted.length ; i++) {
    sdate= new Date(sorted[i].eventDate);
    if(sdate > date) break;
  }

  //do something with sorted[i-1] and sorted[i]
} //getDates
```

To get the last *N* events, use `sorted[i-1]`, `sorted[i-2]`, ... `sorted[i-N]`.

To get the next *N* events, use `sorted[i]`, `sorted[i+1]`, ... `sorted[i+N-1]`.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/27q129Lm/)

Comment: Thanks Rick ! It's working :) but if I want to change it in the future and get the next/previous  2 or 3 events not just one, how can I change the code ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var events = [
    {eventId:1, eventDate: "Wen Apr 01 2015 18:41:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace:"Dortmund, DE"},
    {eventId:2, eventDate: "Sun Apr 05 2015 23:41:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace:"Budapest, HU"},
    {eventId:3, eventDate: "Fri Apr 03 2015 13:41:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace:"Madrid, ES"},
    {eventId:4, eventDate: "Mon Jun 01 2015 22:00:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace:"London, EN"}
    ];

 // sort the events 
 var sortedEvents = events.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(a.eventDate) - new Date(b.eventDate);
  });

var now = new Date("Sun Apr 05 2015 15:00:00");
var futureEvents = [];
var previousEvents = [];

// finding out the next event. Go from the earliest to the newest. When you find the first later than "now", get it
for(var i = 0; i < sortedEvents.length; i++){
  if(new Date(sortedEvents[i].eventDate) > now) {
    futureEvents.push(sortedEvents[i]);
    }
}

// finding out the previous event. Go from the newest to the earliest and when you find the first earlier than "now", get it
for(var i = sortedEvents.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  if(new Date(sortedEvents[i].eventDate) < now) {
    previousEvents.push(sortedEvents[i]);
    }
}

console.log("now: " + now);
console.log("next event: " + futureEvents.length ? futureEvents[0].eventDate : undefined);
console.log("previous event: " + previousEvents.length ? previousEvents[0].eventDate : undefined);
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/andrerpena/pen/WbBwbG

If you want to get more than one future event, or more than one previos event.. just iterate through `futureEvents` or `previousEvents`. For example, the next two events are `futureEvents[0]` and `futureEvents[1]`

Comment: Thanks a lot andrerpena! Your code is working :) but if I want to change it in the future and get the next/previous  2 or 3 events not just one, how can I change your code ?

Comment: Why not creating a list of "all future events" and "all previous events" so you an get how many you want? I'm gonna show you

Comment: @godzo101, I edited the question for your new requirement. If you find this answer useful, please upvote and mark as accepted. Thank you.

Comment: your code is working. I'm new here and I'm not able to upvote cause  I don't have enough reputation ... and also I cannot accept 2 answer (yours and Rick s ) but as soon as I get the reputation I will upvote your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can simply do it using open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com)

```js
var events = [
    {eventId:1, eventDate: "Wen Apr 01 2015 18:41:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace:'Dortmund, DE'},
    {eventId:2, eventDate: "Sun Apr 05 2015 23:41:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace:'Budapest, HU'},
    {eventId:3, eventDate: "Fri Apr 03 2015 13:41:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace:'Madrid, ES'},
    {eventId:4, eventDate: "Mon Jun 01 2015 22:00:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace:'London, EN'},
    {eventId:100, eventDate: "Mon Aug 31 2015 22:00:00 GMT+0300", eventPlace:'London, EN'}
    ]
;


var result1 = jinqJs().from(events).orderBy('eventDate').where(function(row){return Date.parse(row.eventDate) < Date.parse('Sun Apr 05 2015 15:00:00');}).top(1).select();

var result2 = jinqJs().from(events).orderBy('eventDate').where(function(row){return Date.parse(row.eventDate) > Date.parse('Sun Apr 05 2015 15:00:00');}).bottom(1).select();

var result = jinqJs().from(result1,result2).select();

document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + '</pre><br><br>';
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fordth/jinqJs/master/jinqjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks NYTom but I don't want to include another lib to my project if is not completly neccessary :)